# dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--install): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Tags: 16.04, dpkg, deb, elasticsearch

I am working to install elasticsearch5.4.0.deb in ubuntu 16.04 Docker, 
 while installing its throw below error:

```
Preparing to unpack elasticsearch-5.4.0.deb ...
Creating elasticsearch group... OK
Creating elasticsearch user... OK
Unpacking elasticsearch (5.4.0) ...
Setting up elasticsearch (5.4.0) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu17) ...
Couldn't write '4 4 1 7' to 'kernel/printk', ignoring: Read-only file system
Couldn't write '65536' to 'vm/mmap_min_addr', ignoring: Read-only file system
Couldn't write '1' to 'kernel/kptr_restrict', ignoring: Read-only file system
Couldn't write '2' to 'net/ipv6/conf/default/use_tempaddr', ignoring: Read-only file system
Couldn't write '176' to 'kernel/sysrq', ignoring: Read-only file system
Couldn't write '1' to 'fs/protected_symlinks', ignoring: Read-only file system
Couldn't write '1' to 'net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies', ignoring: No such file or directory
Couldn't write '1' to 'net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter', ignoring: Read-only file system
Couldn't write '1' to 'net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter', ignoring: Read-only file system
Couldn't write '1' to 'fs/protected_hardlinks', ignoring: Read-only file system
Couldn't write '1' to 'kernel/yama/ptrace_scope', ignoring: No such file or directory
Couldn't write '2' to 'net/ipv6/conf/all/use_tempaddr', ignoring: Read-only file system
Couldn't write '262144' to 'vm/max_map_count', ignoring: Read-only file system
dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 elasticsearch
```

I have resinstall dpkg,still same issue, suggest me how to fix this.

Comment: Not a problem with dpkg. The package `elasticsearch-5.4.0.deb` is not in the Ubuntu repositories. Consider filing a bug report with whomever or wherever you got that package from.

Comment: You can try with skipping the kernel parameters setup:
`export ES_SKIP_SET_KERNEL_PARAMETERS=true && apt-get install elasticsearch`